# VBA user-defined function not run because of invalid argument input

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-2016

I have an Excel 2016 VBA UDF (user-defined function) that looks this;

```
Public Function AddUDF(Param1 As Single, Param2 As Single)
    'Code implementation
End Function
```

Contents in Cell `A1`, `A2` are inputs to the arguments `Param1`, `Param2`.

When cells A1 and A2 contains numbers, the UDF runs normally as expected. When one of the cells contains a string such as "N.A", this UDF is not run and the value `#VALUE!` is returned. I know the UDF is not run because I put a breakpoint into the UDF and the breakpoint is not reached at all.

How do I get the UDF to run?

Comment: Change you params to variants.

Comment: @ Scott Craner, that's the answer! Please put it down as answer and I will mark it as the answer. You deserve the extra points!

Comment: It depends what you're doing with the arguments.  If you're performing a sum on them you'll always get an error if they're not numbers.

Comment: @ Darren Bartrup-Cook, as long as the UDF runs, I can detect the data type and handle cases when the input is invalid.

Comment: If your inputs will always be cell references, then change input type to `Range` and handle `Range.Value` exceptions accordingly, but if you would use it like `=AddUDF($A$1, 16.5)` then you'll need `Variant` params.

Comment: Yep, go with Scotts answer then.  You may want to look at Chip Pearsons site on returning errors from UDFs - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your Parameter set to `Single` it is telling Excel not accept anything but numbers.

Change the Parameters to Variant then Test to ensure the type you want:

```
Public Function AddUDF(Param1 As Variant, Param2 As Variant)
    If Not (IsNumeric(Param1) And IsNumeric(Param2)) Then
        AddUDF = "not numbers"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'the rest of your code.
End Function
```

Comment: Also worth noting, numeric cells in Excel are `Double`, not `Single`.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct?  If I enter _1_ & _2_ it returns _3_, _A_ and _B_ returns _AB_, _1_  and _A_ returns _#VALUE_.  How about `If Not (IsNumeric(Param1) And IsNumeric(Param2)) Then` and `AddUDF = CVErr(xlErrNA)`

Comment: It was just a suggestion that I did not test, You are correct. @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook to be fair, OP's implementation is `'Code implementation` - answers that don't offer a readily copy/paste-able implementation that works flawlessly, shouldn't be answerers' problem ;-)